# Why is textColor in android:textAppearance ignored?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I use android support library, which version I don not know because I do not know of a way how to check it. The problem I am facing that apparently the value for android:textColor attribute is ignored. If I define a style and assign it to textAppearance of EditText the color textColor is ignored.

So, I have a following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- This text should be red, but it is black -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text color via TextAppearance"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

    <!-- The hint should be green, but it is grey -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint color via TextAppearance"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText" />

     <!-- Text is red as set in android:textColor -->
     <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text color via android:textColor"
        android:textColor="#880000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Hint is green as set in android:textColorHint -->
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint color via android:textColorHint"
        android:textColorHint="#008800"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have defined the following style:

```
<!-- Text Appearance -->
<style name="TextAppearance.EditText" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColor">#880000</item>      <!-- this color is ignored -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#008800</item>  <!-- this color is ignored -->
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Is this a bug in support library or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere along the line, the wrong/default value for `textColor` is being picked up and applied. You can force the `android:textColor` that you define in `android:textAppearance` to be used by setting `android:textColor="@null"` in your XML for `EditText`. This should work for `android:textColorHint` as well.

(This reflects the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45198884/6287910) to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196244/android-textcolor-ignored-in-androidtextappearance-of-the-edittext/45198884#45198884).)

Answer (score 0):

Use

`style="@style/TextAppearance.EditText"`

instead of

`android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.EditText"`

It should work!

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this? What is the android:textAppearance used for then?

Comment: follow [this](https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/) link and jump to the Text Appearance section. you may get some idea about using it properly. :)

Comment: Exactly how I am using it. BTW. If you have not read the question it is mostly revolving around why is textColor attribute ignored?