# Android: textColor ignored in android:textAppearance of the EditText

Tags: android, android-styles

Is there any reason why is `textColor` property being ignored when it is set via custom `textAppearance` style?

```
<style name="EditTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item> <!-- IGNORED -->
</style>
```

Setting style in XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/EditTextAppearance"
    />
```

For some reason, default theme control color is not overridden by this style.

The only way how I am able to set color is by setting `textColor` property in `EditText` (but this is not what I want):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/EditTextAppearance"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    />
```

Note, custom `textAppearance` with `textColor` created for `TextView` works without problem.

I tried to replace `EditText` by `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` or `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` but the result was the same. Still not working. So the problem is not in `EditText` implementation.

I found question with the same problem [Why is textColor in android:textAppearance ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548002/why-is-textcolor-in-androidtextappearance-ignored). Unfortunately, without answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, the wrong/default value for `textColor` is being picked up and applied. You can force the `android:textColor` that you define in `android:textAppearance` to be used by setting `android:textColor="@null"` in your XML for `EditText`.

Comment: I did not expect that soultion can be this simple. Thank you!

Comment: the sad thing about this is that you'd have to always remember to add android:textColor="@null"..

Answer (score 1):

`android:textColor` ignored in `android:textAppearance` of the `EditText` because `android:editTextColor` attribute always overrides text color of the `EditText` (don ask me why, its about crazy droid).

But all works fine if you add this attribute to your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:editTextColor">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know why is `textAppearance` ignoring `textColor` when style is created as described in question, but I think I have found another way how to set `textColor` via style, so somebody might find it useful.

I was playing with `EditText` colors so I've created custom theme and tried to set `editTextColor` property, which surprisingly worked:

```
<!-- consider to extend application theme over default "Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText" to achieve consistent look and feel -->
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color...</item>    <!-- underline color -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color...</item> <!-- underline color on focus -->
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/blue</item> <!-- ACCEPTED -->
</style>
```

Setting theme:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/EditTextAppearance"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
    />
```

At this moment you have custom `"@style/EditTextAppearance"` and `"@style/EditTextTheme"`. The good thing is, that you can **merge** `"@style/EditTextAppearance"` into the `"@style/EditTextTheme"` as follows:

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    ...
    <item name="editTextColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

This way, you just have to set only theme in your `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
    />
```

Current solution is almost perfect, but it would be better, if `textColor` will be set in textAppearance style, so I've tried to remove `editTextColor` from theme and replace it by `textColor` property set in textAppearance style `@style/EditTextAppearance`.

```
<style name="EditTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item> <!-- APPLIED if appearance is part of the theme -->
</style>

<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color...</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color...</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EditTextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

This way `textColor` contained in `textAppearance` is finally applied!